# Generating Random Numbers Based on Some Condition

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I would like to generate random numbers : a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3

I would like there to be a condition such that:

- a3 > a2 > a1
- b3 > b2 > b1

I do not know how to do this directly, so I tried to generate a large data frame of numbers  and only keep rows that match this condition:

```
a1 = rnorm(100000,10,10)
a2 = rnorm(100000,10,10)
a3 = rnorm(100000,10,10)
b1 = rnorm(100000,10,10)
b2 = rnorm(100000,10,10)
b3 = rnorm(100000,10,10)

my_data = data.frame(a1, a2, a3, b1, b2,b3)
```

This data frame looks like this:

```
head(my_data)
          a1         a2        a3         b1        b2         b3
1  5.6713342 -4.5930442  6.063861 28.9258586 -1.073999 23.7398862
2 17.5791993  5.1482061  6.683438  9.2969640  6.438304 10.2569026
3 13.9389949  8.9943351  1.089840 12.9340164 22.099974 -0.6791567
4 16.0257008 10.4139726 18.469092 10.9470812 20.105047  0.4710750
5 -0.1370202  0.9112077  4.349729 11.9442915 22.318155  8.7671923
6 18.8508432 -3.6210024  3.022941  0.6319464 14.406452 25.2002712
```

I then tried to make an "indicator" variable that indicates whether a row should be deleted or kept based on whether or not it matches the conditions:

```
my_data$indicator_a2_a1 = ifelse(my_data$a2 > my_data$a1, "TRUE", "FALSE")
my_data$indicator_a3_a2 = ifelse(my_data$a3 > my_data$a2, "TRUE", "FALSE")
my_data$indicator_a3_a1 = ifelse(my_data$a3 > my_data$a1, "TRUE", "FALSE")

my_data$indicator_b2_b1 = ifelse(my_data$b2 > my_data$b1, "TRUE", "FALSE")
my_data$indicator_b3_b2 = ifelse(my_data$b3 > my_data$b2, "TRUE", "FALSE")
my_data$indicator_b3_b1 = ifelse(my_data$b3 > my_data$b1, "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

With these indicators, the data now looks like this:

```
          a1         a2        a3         b1        b2         b3 indicator_a2_a1 indicator_a3_a2 indicator_a3_a1 indicator_b2_b1 indicator_b3_b2 indicator_b3_b1
1  5.6713342 -4.5930442  6.063861 28.9258586 -1.073999 23.7398862           FALSE            TRUE            TRUE           FALSE            TRUE           FALSE
2 17.5791993  5.1482061  6.683438  9.2969640  6.438304 10.2569026           FALSE            TRUE           FALSE           FALSE            TRUE            TRUE
3 13.9389949  8.9943351  1.089840 12.9340164 22.099974 -0.6791567           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE            TRUE           FALSE           FALSE
4 16.0257008 10.4139726 18.469092 10.9470812 20.105047  0.4710750           FALSE            TRUE            TRUE            TRUE           FALSE           FALSE
5 -0.1370202  0.9112077  4.349729 11.9442915 22.318155  8.7671923            TRUE            TRUE            TRUE            TRUE           FALSE           FALSE
6 18.8508432 -3.6210024  3.022941  0.6319464 14.406452 25.2002712           FALSE            TRUE           FALSE            TRUE            TRUE            TRUE
```

Finally, I isolated rows in which all indicators were TRUE:

```
final_file <- my_data[which(my_data$indicator_a2_a1 == "TRUE" & my_data$indicator_a3_a2 == "TRUE" & my_data$indicator_a3_a1 == "TRUE" & my_data$indicator_b2_b1 == "TRUE" & my_data$indicator_b3_b2 == "TRUE" &  my_data$indicator_b3_b1 == "TRUE"), ]

 dim(final_file)
[1] 2754   12
```

This was successfully accomplished the task - but I was wondering if there is a more "efficient" way to perform this task. For example, I randomly generated 100000 rows, but only 2754 of these rows (~ 2%) met the condition I had wanted. The other problem is that I had to manually create 6 indicator variables to make sure all conditions were respected - had there been more conditions, I would have been required to manually create a large number of indicator variables to ensure that all the conditions were respected.

**My Question:** Is there a way to randomly generate data according to some conditions such that ALL rows produced would meet these conditions? **Could this be done with a WHILE LOOP?**

I would like to tell the computer:  Generate 1000 rows of random data in which:

- a3 > a2 > a1
- b3 > b2 > b1

**Can this be done directly?**

Thanks!

Comment: Given 3 numbers, there are 6 permutations, `factorial(3)`, so the proportion of random triplets in order will be about 1/6, 0.1666667 or 16.7%. If you insist on two triplets meeting that criterion, the expected proportion drops to 0.1666667^2, 0.02777778 or 2.8%. To do better you will have to change your algorithm along the lines of the suggested answers. Your approach can be improved as far as speed, but the yield will not change.

Answer (score 2):

A "direct" method could be creating your variables sequentially using `tibble`:

```
fun <- function(n) {
    tibble(a3 = rnorm(n),
           a2 = a3 - abs(rnorm(n)),
           a1 = a2 - abs(rnorm(n)),
           b3 = rnorm(n),
           b2 = b3 - abs(rnorm(n)),
           b1 = b2 - abs(rnorm(n))) 
}

fun(10)

       a3     a2      a1       b3      b2     b1
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -0.211 -0.901 -2.09   -0.988   -1.61   -2.40 
 2 -0.543 -2.04  -2.18   -0.0840  -1.06   -2.41 
 3 -0.190 -1.22  -1.41   -0.00393 -1.46   -1.73 
 4  2.11   1.36   1.20   -1.06    -2.21   -3.39 
 5  0.653 -0.156 -0.313   1.41     0.301  -0.539
 6 -1.16  -1.46  -2.71    0.387   -1.40   -4.00 
 7  1.56   0.865  0.676   1.18     0.863  -0.296
 8  1.01   0.544  0.0511  0.318    0.0864 -1.76 
 9  0.636  0.165 -1.83    0.929    0.905   0.210
10  0.633 -0.269 -1.01    0.466   -0.0685 -0.445
```

Answer (score 1):

Does simply generating a list of random numbers for a and b and then sorting it using the sort() function work for your use case? The following code matches your specified conditions

```
a = rnorm(3,10,10)
b = rnorm(3,10,10)

a.ordered = sort(a)
b.ordered = sort(b)

df = data.frame(numbers = c(a.ordered,b.ordered),
                row.names = c("a1","a2","a3","b1","b2","b3"))

df
```